# Regex: match certain code that is NOT commented out

Tags: regex

I'm looking for all code branch points in a 1000 line piece of code.  That is, I want to find each occurrence of {if, elseif, for, switch, while, etc.} which is *not* behind a comment "%".

How?

---

*examples*

In `if(x > 50)` match *if*.

In `func(x) % What do I tell my boss if this doesn't work?` don't match *if*.

---

*Update*

Justin 'jjnguy' Nelson came with an answer that worked using basic regex.  (Thanks Justin)  However I had anticipated the solution requiring regex [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  Does anyone have a solution that uses lookaround?  I'm having trouble getting my attempts to work.

Comment: Can you provide an example and an expected outcome? This is a little to vague to have a valid response, IMHO.

Comment: @John Regular expressions of all flavors have support for "not". Isn't that enough for you? Also, "one moment" does not really call for a comment. :)

Comment: what does `func(x, 'switch it on', 'for (3) minutes')` match?

Comment: Good point.  I need to filter out matches within strings too. ... hmmm  I might just use my eyeballs for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be very simple, I believe, if you assume no multi-line comments, and no comment chars in String literals:

```
/^[^%]*(if|elseif|for|switch|while|etc)/
```

This will match the given keywords as long as there is no `%` before them.

Comment: And no keywords in quotes  `variable = 'while fishing'`

Comment: This appears to work, except that my regex is setup for multiple lines, so I had to modify to `/^[^%\n]*(if|elseif|for|switch|while|etc)/`

Answer (score 0):

This is my perception, it could be wrong.
You would have to use a parser specific to the language.
On the other hand, comments usually follow a strict behavior order,
that has to do with escaped/non-escaped, to end of line, line spanning, etc..

These rules can usually be applied with a regular expression because
comments don't follow language rules per se. Its not easy though, but its doable.
After they are stripped out, you can apply another regex to whats left to find
keywords.